# Ubuntu 16.04.1 Chromium (Vivaldi) tearing

Tags: 16.04, chromium, tearing

I'm a newbie. This is a snapshot of my hardware.

[image: hardware_screenshot]

And this is my problem with Chromium (Chrome or Vivaldi, Firefox works fine)

[image: problems_snapshot]

What I must to do to resolve this problem?

Comment: Your screenshots are the same. Please edit and actually add your hardware specs which are very important. Also please add information regarding of any proprietary (Nvidia) drivers you installed, if applicable.

Comment: Sorry! My fail.

Comment: Just updated a links

Comment: Thanks. In futire please copy the relevant text (with code tags) instead of a terminal screenshoot. That said, I noticed you have a Skylake CPU (and the associated Intel Graphics). AFAIK, those still require Grub parameters to work properly but I'm not sure which ones so let's wait for some answers.

Comment: >>>In futire please copy the relevant text (with code tags) instead of a terminal screenshoot.

Ok, I go it.

Comment: screenshots: both look still same, no difference...